# Does $2$ commute in a ring?

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification

Let $R$ be a Ring. Define $1$ to be the multiplicative identity of $R$ and define $2:= 1+1.$

In general, does it hold that $2x=x2$?

From distributivity I would think $\ 2x=(1+1)x=x+x=x(1+1)=x2\ $, but I'm not certain if this is a valid proof.

Comment: That's a great proof!

Comment: It's clearly a valid proof. The only thing you didn't mention is why $1+1$ must be a member of the ring (which it is, but you didn't justify it).

Comment: @AdamRubinson $1+1$ must be a member because $1$ is a member of the ring, and the ring is closed under addition.
Thank you both for your answers, I would mark them as accepted if I could for comments.

Comment: Title: not all rings have a $1$. So $2$ need not be an element in any ring.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I believe you're wrong: One of the axioms of a ring $R$ is that **$1$** $\in R.\ $ See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Definition. If we defined $\ 2:= 1 + 1,\ $ then since $R$ is an Abelian *group* under addition, and *group* has closure, it follows that $2\in R.$

Comment: @AdamRubinson I agree that rings should have a $1$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917370/is-0-neq-1-a-necessary-ring-axiom) for example, but not everyone sees this so. [This MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22579/what-are-the-reasons-for-considering-rings-without-identity) gives some examples.

Comment: @DietrichBurde interesting. I was just going off of Wikipedia's definitions.

Comment: It's possible that $2 = 0$.  It doesn't invalidate the proof but it is worth remembering.  For example, you have not proved that there is an element other than $0$ and $1$ which commutes with all elements.